# TCL issues -10007 error when using oo:class, 1 case and solution

Tags: syntax-error, tcl, curly-braces

This is both a (maybe) bug report, and a question and answers. You have TCL 8.6, on LINUX RHEL6 64 bits, and you see this cryptic message:

```
-10007
    while executing
        "oo::class create DlgClass {
                  method addInstDevBasedProc {} {
                                foreach inst_name [ my getInstsForPmExecute ] {
                                         puts "Inst:$inst_name}"
                                ..."
    (file "moma.tcl" line 1)
```

What happened?
Well, it is all about a missing left brace in the `puts "Inst:$inst_name}"`, right after the `$` sign.
This of course does not mean that other type of mistakes cannot yield the same error code. Unfortunately, I have issues with logging in to the news-group of TCL, and report the message, but wanted to spread the word.
I suggest that TCK have a more meaningful error message for this, in future releases.

Comment: Do you have a link to enough of your code that I can reproduce this to determine the exact nature of the bug? There's enough complexity within TclOO that the fragment in your trace isn't enough for me to determine what's up. Also, report issues in the Tcl issue tracker at http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/tktnew

Comment: Hi Donal.</br>
oo::class create DlgClass {

    method addInstDevBasedProc {} {
    foreach inst_name [ my getInstsForPmExecute ] {
      puts "Inst:$inst_name}"
      set inst_h [ pmGetInst $inst_name ]
      if { ! [ my patternMatchedForThisOOInst? $inst_h ] } {
        my setUdbInstPropForCurOOInst $inst_h [ my getPatBasicPatternMatPropName ] [ my getPatternForMatch ]
      }
    }
    global CC_OK
    return $CC_OK
    }

  }

Comment: I can't get the newlines done right, sorry...

Comment: I can guess pretty much where the newlines are. (Semicolons `;` also work.)  I wonder whether `CC_OK` is set to that odd value (`-10007`) at the point when you ran the code. If so, it's like the code doing something a little unexpected with the unbalanced braces. Or perhaps something is returning TCL_ERROR without setting the interpreter result to an error message, though that should normally be cleared after each (non-bytecoded) command. So many possibilities for what might be going boom…

Comment: Hi Donal.CC_OK is undefiend